# Grub Bootloader issue with Dual Boot/Dual Drive Install Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: dual-boot, uefi, bootloader, grub-efi, boot-partition

So, I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside my Windows 10 Pro. However, I am sure that I am complication it by trying to install Ubuntu on a separate nvme ssd drive. So to elaborate, my Windows 10 installation is on a Samsung 860 Evo 1TB Sata SSD which is nearly full, I believe Ubuntu recognizes it as /sda and where I chose to install Ubuntu to was my new Western Digital SN750 1TB nvme ssd. It's designated at nvme0n1p1. I chose the automatic install mode since it detected my windows installation and decided to install on the nvme drive, however the problem I have is that, it said there would be a bootloader to select which operating system I want to boot to, and it does not appear. I am lazy and do not want to have to spam F9 to go to my boot options to select UEFI Ubuntu to boot into Ubuntu everytime I want to use Ubuntu. I was expecting that the Grub Bootloader would pop up and I would be able to choose to boot to Windows 10 or Ubuntu each time I power on my laptop. I don't know how to fix this, or what It would take, but I would rather find a solution than have to always press f9 and scroll through my bios boot menu to boot to ubuntu. Thanks for whoever decides to help me.

Comment: You say f9, so is this an HP? HP and maybe others require UEFI update. Many SSD also require SSD firmware update. But the HP's seem to sync BCD with HP UEFI and that resets boot order. Then the only thing that works is to boot into UEFI and change boot order from within UEFI.

Comment: @oldfred It is an Hp Laptop. Its fully up to date. The SSD does not need to be updated. The Ubuntu installation worked just fine. I can manually Boot to it by Pressing F9 to select the Ubuntu OS. When I do so it does take me to a Bootloader that is similar to the one you see when you are booting from a live cd/usb. I can then select Ubuntu(the top default option) and it will boot into my Ubuntu installation perfectly fine. If I do not select F9 at boot, then the laptop boots directly to my usual Windows 10 installation. There should be one Boot Menu that incorporates both options.

Comment: Note that grub only boots working Windows. And Windows updates may turn fast start up back on or change UEFI settings to defaults. In those cases just boot Windows directly from UEFI and check UEFI settings. Then grub will work again.

Answer (score 0):

Im dumb. The solution is to change the UEFI boot option in my bios boot order to UEFI Ubuntu, which makes the laptop but to the Grub2 Bootloader. Inside that contains the entry to the Windows Bootloader on /sda, which when I select loads Windows instead of Ubuntu as it should. This is now working exactly how I wanted it to.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am glad you solved your problem. Don't forget to accept your answer as correct by clicking on the grey check mark next to the answer and turn it green. This will help others.