# Dual boot only booting into Windows, no option to choose between Windows or Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have a problem. I have installed Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 on my HP Envy x360 laptop. I went trough the whole setting-up process and at the end Ubuntu told me to restart my computer, so I did. Then it said 'Please remove the installation medium, then press ENTER, so I removed my USB-stick and pressed ENTER. But when I turned my laptop back on it booted straight into Windows without giving me the option to choose my OS. I did some research and figured out that I probably have to turn on Legacy Boot, so I tried to change that in the BIOS but the option seems to not be there. (I have already turned Secure Boot off) I did some research and found out that the Legacy Boot option apparently isn't available in newer versions of the HP-BIOS.

Do I have to turn Legacy Mode on, and if so, how do I do that if it isn't available in my BIOS?

Mij C drive in Windows has shrunk though, so Ubuntu has claimed the 125GB of storage that I gave it. So the OS is definitely somewere on my drive and I don't think someting went wrong with the installation of Ubuntu.

Does anyone have a clue? I would really aprecieate the help.

Greetings, Ezra

Comment: Do not turn on Legacy boot if UEFI system. Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? How you boot install media is then how it installs. You should always boot in UEFI mode. HP often needs UEFI update, SSD firmware update and then in UEFI settings (not boot menu) change boot order. HP seems to sync with Windows BCD which reverts Windows to first. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331889/grub-bootloader-issue-with-dual-boot-dual-drive-install-windows-10-ubuntu-20-10

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.
I think I did install Ubuntu in UEFI mode, so why does it not boot then? Can I maybe install Ubuntu again to check if I actually installed it correctly? And how do I delete the old copy because it has eaten a potion of my diskspace, will it just overwrite?

Comment: Did you go into HP's one time boot and see if ubuntu entry boots? And in UEFI settings change to Ubuntu first in boot order?

Comment: Wow it worked. I just had to enter the right menu. I tought the option between windows and ubunto would appear by itself, but I had to access the right menu by pressing f9 while booting up. Thanks a lot for the help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

With Hp the keys vary by model but usually are

Boot Menu key <kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>f9</kbd>

UEFI Menu key <kbd>esc</kbd> <kbd>f10</kbd>

And HP does not seem to keep changes by efibootmgr which grub uses or with most systems you can use to change boot order. They may be syncing with Windows BCD.

So best to make sure UEFI is up to date as an update may reset to default settings.
Windows updates may also reset some UEFI settings.

And then in UEFI Boot Menu and a boot tab, change boot order to have Ubuntu first.
Grub will only boot working Windows, so if Windows turns fast start up back on, or needs chkdsk from abnormal shutdown or other issue, you may be able to directly boot Windows from UEFI Boot menu (and Windows f8 for repairs?)

Some related HP 360 posts, not all seem to be the same configuration:

[Windows 10 won't boot after dual boot installation - Optane volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1204386/windows-10-wont-boot-after-dual-boot-installation-optane-volume)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2439220

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2359510

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1858477#p1858477

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414086

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's UEFI overwrites your old BIOS to start Ubuntu as default, so with your motherboard so overwritten into UEFI you need to use F2 repeatedly at bootup to get into the UEFI screens. Or, F8 to get into the Ubuntu boot selection menu. However, if you press nothing you will arrive to a terminal type screen with four or five lines, on which you use arrow keys to move the highlight indicating your boot selection to the bottom of the list where you will find Windows 10 listed. Then Press enter and you will boot into Windows. Don't wait to read it because it lasts only seconds. Once you press the down arrow key the first time the clock stops and you can go more slowly.   But!  Conversely, Windows 10 will overwrite the UEFI back to a BIOS and not want to let Ubuntu open again. Then you need to press Delete repeatedly at bootup, rather than F2, and you will find yourself back in the old familiar BIOS screens you are used to, where you select the hard drive you want in the boot menu. I hope you used two hard drives for dual boot. UEFI and BIOS name the drives differently, and that will throw you into confusion till you figure out which drive you really want to boot up. You will find that your computer keeps overwriting the motherboard from UEFI to BIOS and back again when you switch operating systems, so the key you need to use to get to boot selection will keep changing as well.  This happens with all the old BIOS motherboards, new ones now mostly all use UEFI rather than BIOS, because it allows overclocking to be controlled more easily. Windows will eventually use UEFI as well, but for now, it's something we have to live with if we want dual boot for both operating systems. Do not enable "fast boot" in BIOS or you will make trouble getting into either BIOS or UEFI! If you do that, you will need to remove the BIOS memory's battery off of the motherboard, and clear the memory by unplugging and pressing the start button to drain the charge off the memory, to make it forget "fast boot", and then put it back in again, after which it will default again to the original motherboard BIOS system.

Comment: I use ASUS motherboards usually, and AMD processors, not proprietary stuff like HP. Back in the old days motherboards didn't change the BIOS much, whereas UEFI gets updated, so HP, Gateway, and some other older proprietary motherboards may suddenly be updated and lose the memory of their proprietary boot selection keys. If so, then try Delete and F2 at boot time. Hit them both, one will work. The other one won't . It works for me when I forget which O.S. I was using last time.