# Grub menu not showing on startup

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

I have dual booted my HP Pavilion g6 Notebook PC with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS alongside Windows 10.

Whenever I restart my PC, it is directly loading into Windows by default without showing the grub menu. Now every time I turn on my PC, I have to press <kbd>Esc</kbd> button, and then <kbd>F9</kbd> and <kbd>enter</kbd> and there I have to select `ubuntu` file and then the grub menu shows up and there I can select Ubuntu or Windows.

I want the grub menu to show automatically Whenever I turn on my PC.

Here is a list of things I've tried.

1. Secure boot is disabled in Windows 10.
2. Fast startup is off in Windows power settings.
3. bcdedit is set to

   ```
   bcdedit/set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
   ```

   and I even tried,

   ```
   bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
   ```
4. Ubuntu grub menu is up to date.
5. In `/etc/default/grub` file,

   ```
   GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
   ```

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. HP also typically requires you to change boot order in UEFI settings screen for boot not one time boot menu.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Yes, I have installed ubuntu in UEFI mode.

Comment: Boot repair summary - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HTyvFnsbn8/
Boot info summary - https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pT5CHQYrxN/

Comment: Both Links timed out, will try again later.

Comment: Okay. Let's see. Thank you

Comment: Install looks correct. Grub & typical instructions to use efibootmgr to change boot order do not work with HP. Not sure if HP syncs with BCD. See last line in report on BCD entry you can try. HP just go into HP's UEFI and boot tab and change boot order there. HP Envy - use UEFI to change boot order https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332255/dual-boot-only-booting-into-windows-no-option-to-choose-between-windows-or-ubun You may want to remove all the duplicate `Internal Hard Disk` in UEFI. Similar to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1198221/cloning-ssd-also-cloned-boot-options/1198228#1198228

Comment: How to know which are the duplicate Internal Hard Disk , they all looks the same.

Comment: That is what a duplicate is. Just keep one of all the ones that are the same. If it keeps growing, you have some process in UEFI, Windows or Ubuntu that is creating entry. And eventually UEFI runs out of it NVRAM and fails.