# will ubuntu work on an hp envy 13, specifically envy 13-ba1027nn

Tags: laptop, hp, compatibility

I will start a full stack developer course soon, and i gotta get a laptop that's gonna run Linux, specifically Ubuntu. I've been eyeing envy 13-ba1027nn since it's pretty powerful and cheap ish. Will Ubuntu run on this specific laptop?
Here are the full specs provided by hp:
https://support.hp.com/ro-en/document/c07081104

Comment: https://community.revolut.com/t/please-read-this-first-for-help-how-to-contact-revolut-v1-1/192349

Comment: Similar HP with newer Intel chip. You will need newest version of Ubuntu to have newest kernel & drivers. HP 17-BY4063CL Laptop shows UEFI screens, needed 21.04 since new Intel chip
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462045 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332255/dual-boot-only-booting-into-windows-no-option-to-choose-between-windows-or-ubun

Answer (score 0):

yes it will. I run mine on a 2gb ram server with 2cores allocated to it and have no issues what so ever with a gui.

Comment: if needed here is a link of neofetch: https://i.imgur.com/cdjTTeU.jpeg

Answer (score 0):

of course it will run, ubuntu has a pretty low system requirement, it can even run on my 9 year old computer that has 8 gigs ram, amd fx 8120, compared to windows it is much faster, windows fan speed is 60db, ubuntu is only 10

so if it can run on my 9 year old PC, it can probably run on anything