# Windows 8.1 overwriting bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I have a hp laptop that came with windows 8.1 I have successfully installed ubuntu in another partition. The problem is whenever I turn on my computer it boots into windows 8.1  directly, no grub. So if I shutdown and turn on my computer again like last time but I press `esc` to pause boot I press f9 to see the UEFI boot menu I see ubuntu at the top (I changed the order) and then window bootloader and then any other usb or cd put in. If I go to ubuntu I see grub and it works how I want it to!! when it boots into ubuntu and shutdown and start up again I see grub but if I click windows 8.1 in grub goes into windows I shutdown and it boots back into windows 8.1, no grub.

I have secure boot enabled and faststart disabled.

One other problem is that clicking windows in grub goes straight into windows boot but when I click ubuntu it keeps the background up of grub theme up for 30 seconds before booting into ubuntu.

Thank you.

Comment: install onto a USB memory stick ( or CD or DVD ) a copy of boot repair ... then boot from this and do the repair ... this typically fixes these dual boot problems  ... see  https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: Most with HP have to update UEFI, update SSD firmware and change boot order in UEFI settings, not UEFI boot menu. HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios setup  hp 250 g3  Change boot order in UEFI settings
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2467077 HP Envy - use UEFI to change boot order
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332255/dual-boot-only-booting-into-windows-no-option-to-choose-between-windows-or-ubun

Comment: I have changed the boot order to ubuntu first on the list. And it does the same thing.

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu when ```secure boot``` was enabled? Or did you install it when it was disbled? If it was disabled, and afterwards you enabled it again, that might be the problem. If this doesn't solve the problem, just reinstall ```grub 2``` ( boot from your installation medium, usually a usb-stick, and run ```sudo apt install --reinstall grub```). See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB