# Can't boot to Ubuntu after dual boot installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows

**Context in steps:**

1. Machine with Windows 11.
2. Shrink Windows partition in 120 GB for **Ubuntu 22.04**.
3. Boot to installation with USB.
4. Make 3 partitions: | (1) 18 GB for root (/) | (2) 90 GB for /home | (3) rest for swap
5. Continue with installation (install updates and 3rd party drivers was selected).
6. Installation finishes and says "restart to use Ubuntu".
7. "Remove USB drive and press enter" message with Ubuntu logo.
8. PC reboots directly into Windows.
9. Tried rebooting again and got directly into Windows.
10. Windows Disk Management shows Ubuntu partition as "Not assigned"

I followed this steps in a VM in Windows and after installation the VM rebooted to GRUB. The only different thing is that I did not use the option "install 3rd party drivers".

**PC specs:**

- NVidia 1660 GTX
- HP Omen 15 (Notebook)
- Intel Core i7 9750H
- 16 GB RAM DDR4
- NVMe SSD

Comment: If you use the EFI menu at power-up (some function key that gives you the boot choices of devices or oses), do you get an ubuntu choice?  If you choose it, do you get grub? From grub can you boot ubntu and windows?  Might just be an efi boot selection preference to put the ubuntu choice first.

Comment: Is the EFI menu in the BIOS menus or is it accesed with a different function key?

Comment: It's a different function key, although the ordering is also found under the BIOIS/UEFI settings, and should be changed there or maybe with efibootmgr from Ubuntu.

Comment: HP typically needs UEFI update, and if SSD, SSD firmware update. And you have to change UEFI boot order in UEFI settings (not UEFI boot menu). HP Envy - use UEFI to change boot order
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332255/dual-boot-only-booting-into-windows-no-option-to-choose-between-windows-or-ubun HP - escape + F9 for UEFI boot menu, F10 for UEFI/bios setup For whatever reason HPs do not support boot order changes with efibootmgr. all other systems seem to work ok.

Comment: @ubfan1 and oldfred. I updated BIOS and SSD firmware. After that I went to EFI menu with F9 and got a menu if 4 options: Microsoft, Boot, HP and ubuntu. Selected ubuntu and got "No Valid File Available in the Selected File System".

Comment: A "Valid" file in HP's meaning may be only one named bootmgfw.efi (or maybe labeled "Microsoft Boot..." -- search this site for those and see what's required. Regardless, the grub installer also replaces the device bootloader, (/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi) with shimx64.efi or grubx64.efi, and if you can select the device to boot, that trick gets around HP's namechecks, since only a standard name is used (bootx64.efi).

Comment: Didn't quite understand, should I rename a file? and, can I do this in Windows? I'm stuck in Windows now.

Comment: You can install ```grub2win``` in Windows, and set that as bootloader.

Comment: @JoepieEs To use `grub2win` I need to see the partition of the OS I'm trying to create an entry. But I can't see the partition. Windows disk management shows Ubuntu partition as "not assigned" (adding this to the question)

Comment: If you boot from usb into a live environment, do you see the partition in GParted?