# can't see grub menu on ubuntu 22.04.1 lts installation

Tags: grub2

I have installed windows 11 in one partition and ubuntu 22.04.1 lts in another but when booting it starts windows 11 directly. At no time does the grub menu appear. I've tried to install it with bootrepair but it still doesn't work.

Comment: did you change your BIOS to boot to Ubuntu directly?

Comment: What brand/model system? Did you install Ubuntu in UEFI boot mode? Some like HP, require you to change UEFI boot order in UEFI settings. Just about everyone else recognizes efibootmgr's change of boot order which grub also uses to make Ubuntu first in boot order. But if not UEFI install, that will not work. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install, not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: my model is an hp. I installed ubuntu in uefi mode.  But i don't know how to set the bios for boot Ubuntu directly.

Comment: You need to access your motherboard firmware to change boot priority. If you don't know how to do this, consult the documentation or support for your motherboard. Setting boot priority is not part of Ubuntu or any other operating system.

Comment: Best to check manual for your system. Also see similar: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332255/dual-boot-only-booting-into-windows-no-option-to-choose-between-windows-or-ubun

Comment: I have already entered the bios and I have modified the boot order, but I only get these options: `usb flash drive; os boot manager; internal cd/dvd rom drive; network adapter`. I tried with the first and second (putting them first) but the grub still does not appear

Comment: ah ok, now i got it. I had to enter on the `os boot manager` and select ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)