# Dual boot ubuntu stuck on HP Notebook 14s model windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm trying to install new ubuntu version 21.04/20.04 from my windows 10 but it's stuck after selecting Ubuntu from GRUB.

1. My HP windows BIOS mode us UEFI and disabled Secure boot mode.
2. Downloaded Ubuntu 21.04 from official website and verified with sha256 key
3. Downloaded Rufus and writen ISO image with partition option GPT and UEFI config
4. Restarted system and selected my USB hard drive from Boot Manager
   [USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cklvE.png)
5. After selecting USB, Hard drive, I have chosen Ubuntu from GNU then it got stuck.
   [ubuntu stuck img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsAPZ.png)
6. I tried with nomodeset in GNU grub but the result is same. After quiet splash, i have added nomodeset.
   [grub img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYt3e.png)

Can someone help me to install ubuntu successfully?

Comment: Please do not have pictures of text all text needs to be in the question. Also the first line of the question lists 2 different versions of Ubuntu please be clear what are you trying to install and edit.

Comment: I'm trying to install Ubuntu 21.04 but it got stuck. So, i have tried 20.04 and this version also same, it got stuck.

Comment: Please edit the question to say that. If you are booing from live media you get the choice to try or install there should not be a grub menu at this point. Please be clear on what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. But, here it's not happening for me. It got stuck after selecting the Ubunu. It's not showing the options like 'Try Ubuntu' Or 'Install Ubuntu'. Please refer my screenshots for better understanding.

Comment: I would suggest downloading a new version of the ISO and using a new USB drive make a new live media,

Comment: As suggested above but if the problem persists then try booting without `splash`.

Comment: I have tried with 'nosplash' and it got stuck in the step

[ **] (1 of 2) A start job is running for Wait for udev to Complete Device Initialization (31s / 3min).

And if i remove splash then from the below step it's proceeding further
[ **] (1 of 2) A start job is running for Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling (27s / no limit)

Comment: Is it like the HP 15? HP 15 disable Optane
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/How-to-Disable-Optane-in-Bios-and-set-Disk-Controller-to/td-p/7354483 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331889/grub-bootloader-issue-with-dual-boot-dual-drive-install-windows-10-ubuntu-20-10 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `pci=nomsi` after `quite splash`.

1. Before the [Plymouth](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Plymouth) (boot splash) screen appears, press the <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> key (could be another key, as it depends on the laptop's manufacturer) to enter the **GRUB boot menu**.
2. After you're in the GRUB menu, select `Advanced options for Ubuntu`.

   [image: Grub menu]
3. You'll see a screen similar to this:
   [image: Advanced Options for Ubuntu]
4. Navigate to the latest (topmost) kernel.
5. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to enter edit mode.
6. Find `quiet splash`.
7. Add `pci=nomsi` in front of `quiet splash`.
8. Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to reboot.

Reboot and it should work!