# Problem while dual booting Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I am unable to install Ubuntu along with windows 10 on hp 15s fr2006tu laptop. My ssd is not detected while installing Ubuntu

Comment: Do you have latest UEFI from HP and have you updated SSD firmware? You also in UEFI settings need to change to AHCI, but if dual booting with Windows must install Windows own AHCI driver first or it will not boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233623/workaround-to-install-ubuntu-20-04-with-intel-rst-systems https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331889/grub-bootloader-issue-with-dual-boot-dual-drive-install-windows-10-ubuntu-20-10& https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane & if new chip: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462045

Comment: I have updated SSD firmware and have latest UEFI Bios. There is no option in bios to change to AHCI.

Comment: Does it have Optane?  Used Intel App in Windows to disable Optane, need AHCI driver in Windows.
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2458373&p=14022735#post14022735
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/intel-optane-memory-and-storage-management/9mzng5hzwz1t?activetab=pivot:overviewtab Similar CPU: HP 17-BY4063CL Laptop shows UEFI screens, needed 21.04 since new Intel chip
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462045 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane

Comment: HP 15 11th Gen Intel Core i3 Processor 15.6" (39.62cms) FHD Laptop (8GB/512GB SSD/Win 10/MS Offce/Integrated Graphics/Natural Silver/1.69 Kg), 15s-fr2006TU https://www.amazon.in/dp/B08XNYH4LX/ref=cm_sw_r_wa_apa_glt_i_4BHA07MQC25W56Z9FZ7N?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1.It doesn't have optane

Comment: Did you look at the link on HP17 in first comment, but otherwise similar. He was able to get it to work with 21.04, but not 20.04.

Comment: None of those methods work for me. And I can't hear audio while playing a movie in try Ubuntu option. And also the keyboard sometimes doesn't work..

Comment: So you have installed, but now have audio issues. Best to ask that as a question. Have seen other questions on audio issues, but do not follow those, but someone else may be able to help if seeing that in the title of question.

Comment: I haven't installed Ubuntu. I just tried it by clicking on ' try Ubuntu ' option.

Comment: What have you tried? What version of Ubuntu? What UEFI settings?

Comment: I want to install School Ubuntu 18.04 . When we plugin the Ubuntu installer usb there is an option to try Ubuntu without installing it.I selected 'try Ubuntu' without installing it . I only have option to select the first  boot device and disabled/enable secure boot in the UEFI Bios. I have audio problem and keyboard issues.

Comment: That system is too new for old 18.04. You need 21.04 and may have to wait or install the not yet released 21.10, due in Oct. You can install the testing version of 21.10, but then are a tester and should report any issues. Note the this site does not yet support 21.10 issues.

Comment: Please help me to install School Ubuntu 18.04.It's for educational purpose. Now I have installed School Ubuntu 18.04 in my sandisk pendrive but it doesn't detect Bluetooth ,wifi, audio, keyboard.