# Ubuntu-20.04.2.0 USB installer does not detect internal hard disk of laptop

Tags: hard-drive, live-usb, detect

My laptop is 15s-DU3060TX(i5 11th generation, 8GB RAM, 1 TB Toshiba MQ04ABF100 harddisk).

My laptop does not have SSD. A slot for SSD is there in the laptop.

Laptop has come with preinstalled Windows 10 OS.

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.2.0 as dual boot and created USB bootable device using Rufus. I have chosen GPT as partition scheme and BIOS or UEFI as Target system while making bootable pendrive.

I have disabled fast boot, bitlocker and secure boot. My BIOS shows NON-RAID as status, AHCI as controller type and SATA as controller interface (Image is attached).

During installation, everything goes well till installation type window.

As installation progresses it skips installation type window and partition window appears. But there are no partitions in it.

I opened a terminal in live USB and ran sudo fdisk -l to find whether it lists hard disk or not. It showed only pen drive.

I am really confused whether my laptop will allow me to install Ubuntu alongside windows 10.

[SATA controller in BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18jyw.jpg)

Comment: Have you updated UEFI and you probably need 21.04 to have newest kernel & drivers to support newest hardware. HP 17-BY4063CL Laptop shows UEFI screens, needed 21.04 since new Intel chip
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462045 & https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331889/grub-bootloader-issue-with-dual-boot-dual-drive-install-windows-10-ubuntu-20-10  We do normally suggest using the LTS, so you get 5 years of support. So you will have to update in 9 months.

Comment: Hi oldfred, I have tried with Ubuntu 21.04 and it was installed successfully. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very new hardware typically needs latest version of Ubuntu, and may even need newer kernel & drivers.

Have you updated UEFI firmware & if SSD, SSD firmware? Even new systems may have updates available.

Similar system with very new hardware:
HP 17-BY4063CL Laptop shows UEFI screens, needed 21.04 since new Intel chip

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462045

[Grub Bootloader issue with Dual Boot/Dual Drive Install Windows 10/Ubuntu 20.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331889/grub-bootloader-issue-with-dual-boot-dual-drive-install-windows-10-ubuntu-20-10)

We do normally suggest using the current LTS, so you get 5 years of support. So you will have to update in 9 months.