# Ubuntu or any other linux distro will not install

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, uefi

My uncommon laptop model: 15-au070nb is an hp pavilion notebook. My drive is formatted in the GPT partition format. I try to dualboot my pc.
My problem is that after trying the installer 20+ times (I'm not even kidding) that linux would not install. I've tried every combination of bios settings (I cannot disable secure boot because my bios doesn't have it) I have tried to install in uefi mode and legacy mode, both didn't work.

I tried making the usb several times over with different software like balena etcher or rufus. With rufus I tried the GPT partition scheme with no succes. I tried the MBR with no succes either.
I also tried the 'nomodeset' and the other that I don't remember the name of.

The problem with the installer is that it gets stuck at random moments of the installation the most common part where it gets stuck is with copying files.

It feels like my computer is blocking the installation somehow but windows installs without any problems

Thank you for helping.

Comment: You've provided no specific details; what on-topic OS & release did you use?  did you verify the ISO?  did you verify your write to media? etc.   You've not ruled out user-type procedural errors in what you provided.

Comment: Either your hardware has some unique issue or you're doing something wrong. My guess is that you're doing something wrong. Have you seen that Ubuntu has an official [tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop)?  Please follow all these steps exactly. Also, continue to comb thru your BIOS settings. Every motherboard is different so what you're looking for might be called something slightly different. If you are confused about BIOS setting description, read the documentation for your computer!

Comment: Smells like a possibly flaky/dying USB drive to me. Or the onboard HDD/SSD (which falls under 'hardware' as @Nmath wrote. Without any troubleshooting information, you are asking us to guess and speculate. You don't really need us for that.

Comment: I have verified all the iso with the provided checksums and balena etcher gave a successful validation after burning the usb. I was using ubuntu 21.10 and my graphics are intel hd 520.

Comment: The ssd is fine because windows installed without a problem a year ago and the sandisk utility is reporting my ssd as healthy

Comment: Since you are trying to dual-boot, are you using the "install alongside Windows" option?  And do you have unpartitioned free space before you start the installation?  Or are you trying to manually partition with the "something else" option?

Comment: HP 15 disable Optane
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/How-to-Disable-Optane-in-Bios-and-set-Disk-Controller-to/td-p/7354483 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331889/grub-bootloader-issue-with-dual-boot-dual-drive-install-windows-10-ubuntu-20-10
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot)

Answer (score 0):

In your 'UEFI/BIOS' you have to disable `secure boot`. Otherwise it won't install any Linux distribution or any other than Microsoft Operating System.

> 'Most x86 hardware comes from the factory pre-loaded with Microsoft
> keys. This means the firmware on these systems will trust binaries
> that are signed by Microsoft. Most modern systems will ship with SB
> enabled - they will not run any unsigned code by default, but it is
> possible to change the firmware configuration to either disable SB or
> to enrol extra signing keys.'

and

> 'SB is also not meant to lock users out of controlling their own
> systems. Users can enrol extra keys into the system, allowing them to
> sign programs for their own systems. Many SB-enabled systems also
> allow users to remove the platform-provided keys altogether, forcing
> the firmware to only trust user-signed binaries.'

quotes from [enter link description here](https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot).

So if you cannot disable 'secure boot' in your UEFI/BIOS, you have to enrol the extra keys. Take a look at [enter link description here](https://wiki.debian.org/UEFI) for example.

Or you can try putting your harddisk in another system, install it there, and put the harddisk in your own system again. Although I am not sure if that will work ( missing extra keys in UEFI ).

Will it allow you to install Ubuntu to an external drive? Or does that fail too? If that fails is surely is UEFI that stops the installation proces.

And check the health of your hardware as well.

Hoping to have pointed you in the right direction.

Edit 211113
Are you sure your USB stick is ok? If you have another one, try it with that.

Comment: I have deleted the key database from my system and it still gets stuck on the almost finished copying files but I will try to put my ssd in another system and installing it that way.