# Ubuntu installer cannot detect Windows 11 or partitions for dual install

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

While attempting to install Ubuntu, the installer cannot detect any other operating system or Windows Boot Manager. I set aside a 50GB partition for Ubuntu, but when I try "Something else" during the Installation type step, it cannot detect the partition that I created for the installation either (or any partitions on my SSD whatsoever, however it detects everything on the USB). I've tried with versions 20.04, 21.04, and 21.10. I've tried flashing two different USB sticks, disabled secure boot in BIOS, decrypted BitLocker, tried advanced restart and completely shutting off before booting from the USB, disabled fast startup, and ran chkdsk in windows (no issues). Nothing has changed.

I'm using a brand new HP laptop model 15-dy2097nr, specs are Intel core i7 CPU, 12GB RAM, 256GB SSD, 16GB Intel optane memory, iris xe onboard graphics. Windows 11 was preinstalled. I'm not using a virtual machine or any similar software.

Is there a compatibility issue or some sort of software corruption? Or is there another way I can fix this?

Comment: It's likely a problem with some incompatible drive mode - "RAID" or Intel RST - if the whole drive isn't being detected. Could be also a problem with Fast Startup that should be disabled prior to installing Ubuntu in dual-boot with any Windows 8 or newer, the situation allude to by matigo's comment.

Comment: @matigo I tried both, most recently from shut down then boot. There was no difference in the results.

Comment: @ChanganAuto is there a way to find out if it is, and if so can I disable or change it? edit - the drive itself is being detected, but the partitions aren't

Comment: See this [link](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup) and this [link](https://www.passfab.com/windows-10/disable-fast-boot-windows-10.html) for how to disable fast startup.

Comment: @user68186 followed the guide and disabled it, but it hasn't made a difference

Comment: Yes, you should open UEFI settings and find out. There isn't a generic answer for this because firmwares aren't generic. Your user's manual may or may not have detailed references for all the features and options the UEFI has. Typically HP's have only a few user accessible settings. Then if you find it and it can be changed the choice is AHCI, always. But you have to install AHCI support in Windows otherwise it won't boot.

Comment: Yours likely have some sort of "pseudo-RAID" for the Optane drive. I think that you have to disable this feature for dual-booting but hopefully someone with experience with this kind of systems will give a detailed answer.

Comment: Some more info: HP 15 disable Optane
https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/How-to-Disable-Optane-in-Bios-and-set-Disk-Controller-to/td-p/7354483 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331889/grub-bootloader-issue-with-dual-boot-dual-drive-install-windows-10-ubuntu-20-10 HP 17-BY4063CL Laptop shows UEFI screens, needed 21.04 since new Intel chip
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2462045

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually managed to figure it out, but I had to do two things.

1. Disable Optane Memory. I didn't need the BIOS for this, I had to use an application from Intel and just restart the device.
2. Downgrade to Windows 10. I can upgrade whenever I want, but Windows 11 is just utter garbage and for some reason crashed the Intel apps whenever I tried using them as well as reverting my settings like battery saver to the default completely unprompted.

Thank you to everyone who helped me out with this!

Answer (score 0):

The software is not damaged. It was the same with me.
Start a terminal as admin.
Type manage-bde /?. this shows all options.
manage-bde -status shows you if the HDD is encrypted.
If YES, manage-bde -off and wait. Check with manage-bde -status until protection is disabled.
now it should work.

Comment: Decrypting was one of the first things I tried in windows settings, and checking via the command prompt made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should disable fast boot from windows to see partitions here is an example for windows 10 https://theitbros.com/disable-fast-startup-windows/