# Ubuntu Live USB not booting - only in UEFI mode

Tags: boot, uefi, live-usb, laptop, bios

With this I am at my wit's end. I would really like to install Ubuntu in EFI mode.

### tl;dr

Booting Ubuntu Live USB, EFI does not work. Booting in BIOS mode works. Even though Win10/Lubuntu do boot in EFI mode. On a modern (but not bleeding-edge-modern) system. (Seems to be about GNOME?)

### Prerequisites

- I have a HP ProBook 430 G7

  - Original Win10 install
  - Partition shrunk -> 100GB free, un-allocated disk space
  - SecureBoot disabled, legacy support enabled
  - Processor is Core i5-10210U - reasonably modern, not bleeding edge
- I created two hybrid (EFI/BIOS) Live USB drives with Rufus

  - Ubuntu 22.04.1
  - Lubuntu 22.04.1
  - In boot menu ("F9" for this HP model) each drive shows up as two separate options for boot: "Legacy" or "Efi"
    (Sidenote: Up to now, I never had any problems with Rufus or either of those images on other machines.)

### Possible Boot Combinations

- Lubuntu in BIOS mode: works well
- Ubuntu in BIOS mode: works well
- Lubuntu in EFI mode: Takes forever and a day to boot. Seems to get stuck during boot for at least ten minutes, then over black terminal background, the mouse pointer appears, and finally the LXDE environment pops up.
- Ubuntu in EFI mode: Does not work. Starts booting, delivers some terminal output. Lots of green "Started" (or something like that) notifications appear, and suddenly "[FAILED] Setting color scheme", and later on "[FAILED] Starting GNOME"
- Also, for each combination, starting the live system in "Safe Graphics Mode" does not change the outcome whatsoever.

(all error messages paraphrased, as I am not at the machine right now)

### Questions

- Why? I never had issues with Rufus, the hybrid (EFI/BIOS) USB setup, any of the flash drives in question, or any of the two image files.
- Where does Lubuntu's hang-time come from?
- Why does Gnome start well in BIOS mode, but apparently dies in EFI mode?
- What am I looking for? I don't even really know what set of keywords to google. Googling the error messages leads to unrelated topics.
- What would you need to help me? I am happy to provide any further infos about my setup or transcripts of error messages, if it helps.

Comment: When you made the Live Media are you sure you made it UEFI? Did you verify the the ISO before making the boot device? Se this site https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: Hi @David , no, I did not verify the images, but I used them successfully before in UEFI mode. On a different machine. Also with rufus. So I am 100% certain, that the images as well as the UEFI-capabilities of the live USB drives are okay.

Comment: What model HP? Many have needed UEFI update & if SSD, SSD firmware update. Do you have Optane? That also is an issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331889/grub-bootloader-issue-with-dual-boot-dual-drive-install-windows-10-ubuntu-20-10 & 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162452/problem-installing-ubuntu-in-a-laptop-with-intel-optane

Comment: @oldfred As I initially stated in the question: It is a HP Probook 430 G7. But there is no optane, it is a Samsung SSD. And unlike the questions you linked, the problem is while booting from the Live USB image - way before I could run into any troubles installing Ubuntu on the disk.

Comment: May be similar, they mention some unique settings? Probook G4 470 Ubuntu works fine with UEFI and secure boot. 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2381663 HP Check if Customized UEFI settings available like this  HP ProBook 4340
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2332681&p=13527216#post13527216 HP ProBook 450 G1 Custom UEFI boot or copy to bootx64.efi, delay of a so called "Express Multiboot menu"
http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=164076

Comment: Thank you, @oldfred for your continued support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently, by putting clues of across the internet together, I eventually came across the `nomodeset` boot parameter. Some explaination can be found in this question: [What does nomodeset do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/207175/what-does-nomodeset-do)

With using this boot parameter, Ubuntu was able to boot in EFI mode. But it took a day and a half - at least seven minutes (like it was with the aforementioned Lubuntu live system in EFI mode).

The live system's graphics were were rather low resolution, but I proceeded to install anyway. From there on everything was flawless: Installation went smoothly, I rebooted and was immediately able to select between Win10 and Ubuntu. The on-disk installed Ubuntu booted quickly and smoothly without use of the `nomodeset` parameter. Graphics were looking great and everything works.

So, this answer provides the solution for how to get Ubuntu to live-boot in EFI mode. On the other hand, I still don't know, why both *buntu live systems take forever to boot in EFI mode. But as the live system was only needed once, and the installed system works great, I won't investigate any further. But if anyone has some insights, I would still be interested!